# any alternative way for fixing max time exceeded instead using setting max_execution_time and memory_limit in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, chunks

am getting max time/memory exceeded error while running CRON job which generates pdf files.  I set the following along with laravel chunks then it's working fine..but setting .ini values like this is correct or not.. and is there any other way to overcome this issue. please help.
**ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)**
**ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')**

Comment: The other way to fix it would be to rewrite the part that uses so much memory. Check if there's something weird going on there.

Comment: Surely a cron job is being run by the PHP CLI and there is no `max_execution_time` set for the CLI.

Comment: Cron jobs does not care about max_execution_time, you sure you are using CRONs?

Comment: @Asim am using laravel CRON job when running it throwing this error

Comment: are you running your command through PHP CLI or directly hitting a url through web browser?
max_execution_time  will not have any affect on CLI, try running your crons through CLI.

Comment: ma running command only. initially, I got both max_execution_time 
 and max_memory_limit errors, when I add chunks max_execution_time  got fixed but  max_memory_limit still getting @Asim